# How to avoid a specific pixel won't be processed twice or more for image processing? declare a table?

Tags: arrays, opencv, image-processing, pixel

***How to avoid to process pixels twice or more?***

For example,
if pixel (5, 10) match a certain condition, then i processed this pixel.
And when this pixel match another condition, i don't want it to be processed again.

What's the effective way to save these pixels that i already processed?
And how can i check if a pixel already been processed or not?

The only way i can imagine is to create a 2-D array, if a pixel (5, 10) been processed, then array[5][10] = 1, is there any solution to this?

In OpenCV, is there any API can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's rather vague what you are actually trying to achieve and what the actual processing is, but IMHO you are basically describing *"masking"* or *"masked operations"*.

Comment: "process" here is just a pronoun, it can be pixel value plus 5 or apply gamma or any else. And i don't want pixels been "processed" twice or more times. for example, if a certain pixel value already plus 5 because it match a condition, the next time if it match another condition, i don't want it plus 5 again.

Comment: You can just use Numpy masks, e.g. to add 5 to pixels that are not masked `im[~mask] += 5` See *"Boolean Arrays As Masks"* here https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html

Comment: this isn't specific to numpy. *masks*, as boolean images (1 bit per pixel), are a general concept used all over computer graphics. many OpenCV APIs take a `mask` argument. besides that, masks can be used with regular math.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ok, i'll try to learn to use boolean image, thanks y'all.

Comment: The mask image can be combined into the image itself in some cases. All you need is to reserve one bit of your pixel values. If you determine you don’t ever use more than 128 levels in your processing, for example, then you have one bit to spare that you can use for bookkeeping. With a floating-point image you can mask the least significant bit and use it for bookkeeping. Saving memory this way is not so important any more, memory is cheap, but it was very important in the old days. Nowadays this helps you save cache.